# Java hot redeploy without bundling for development

Tags: java

I've a project that has multiple modules:

```
Parent
\- Main
\- ServiceA
\- ServiceB
...
```

The time it takes to to do `maven install && maven exec:java` on every change is making the development... painful. Spoiled by angular hot deploy, what can I say :)

Is there a Java development workflow - either using IDE, command line build tool or anything of sorts - that allows for hot code redeploying multiple pieces of code without paying the heavy price of bundling?

Idk, perhaps I'm looking for a lightweight alternative to OSGi (both in terms of setup and bundling time). Since the IDE recompiles things on its own, I guess looking for file watcher plus classloader reloader. Even a full JVM restart would probably be acceptable (certainly better than maven's 2 minute build).

I searched a lot, but all solutions I ran into are heavyweight.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on servers and frameworks. You can try solutions described here: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rjc301/ but I think that the best solution is JRebel - unfortunatly it's not free tool

Answer (score 0):

Hot swapping to my knowledge doesn't have a really easy answer.  A JVM restart doesn't really seem like the answer because that will require the classloader to re-load EVERYTHING in your classpath (far outreaching the scope of your project, and can be worse than normal if you define additional custom classpath locations for additional jars).

There is a tool called DCEVM (which I've never used) that acts as a patch for the JVM to allow repeated class reloading during runtime.

I believe your options are to patch the JVM with DCEVM or similar (if similar exists), use the jdb (or an abstraction of it such as what IDEs do) to reload classes from the command line debugger tool, or write up a secondary class loader with a hook that you as the developer/user can access during execution to let it know when to dump it's definitions and grab new ones.  The last option giving you the most flexibility, but is not an lighthearted engineering task to do well.